# enabling incoming connections in Mac OS X Lion firewall via command line

Tags: mac-osx, application-firewall

```
$sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --listapps
ALF: total number of apps = 2 

1 :  /Applications/some.app 
 ( Allow incoming connections ) 

2 :  /Applications/another.app 
 ( Block incoming connections )
```

The above command shows that another.app is a part of my firewall trusted apps list, but it is set to block incoming connections. How can I set it to allow incoming connections from the command line, and make the change effective immediately?

Comment: I discovered that I can do the following to unblock apps `sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp /path/to/app`. However, when I do the above for `/opt/local/apache2/httpd`, and it shows as being unblocked, I still can't reach the web server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I have had same problem and "solved" the problem by unloading / loading MacPorts httpd with the Mac OS X 10.8 application firewall (socketfilterfw) running. Have no idea why this worked. One clue is as soon as I ran the load a prompt popped up asking whether to allow connections. This despite having already entered the MacPorts httpd application in the filewall options GUI.

1. System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall: Turn firewall on if it is off
2. `sudo port unload apache2`
3. `sudo port load apache2`

Before fix:
`Aug 27 22:42:59 mac1 socketfilterfw : Deny _ connecting from mac2 to port _ proto=6`

During fix:

`Aug 27 22:44:05 mac1 socketfilterfw : httpd is listening from :::_ proto=6`

After fix:

`Aug 27 22:45:32 mac1 socketfilterfw : Allow _ connecting from mac2 to port _ proto=6`

I searched for "httpd is listening" and in the past several days this is the only occurrence in the appfilewall log.

Hope this helps someone. I don't know why it worked for me but I have used it twice ... today and about six weeks ago. System reboots ever week.

Answer (score 2):

You can get more info about socketfilterfw by running it with -h:

```
# /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -h
usage: /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw [-c] [-w] [-d] [-l] [-T] [-U] [-B] [-L] [-a listen or accept] [-s file to sign] [-v file to verify] [-p pid to write] [--getglobalstate] [--setglobalstate on | off] [--getblockall] [--setblockall on | off] [--listapps] [--getappblocked <path>] [--blockapp <path>] [--unblockapp <path>] [--add <path>] [--remove <path>] [--getallowsigned] [--setallowsigned] [--getstealthmode] [--setstealthmode on | off] [--getloggingmode] [--setloggingmode on | off] 
...
 --unblockapp <path>           unblock the application at <path>
```

So in your case you can do:

```
# /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp /Applications/another.app
```

If you still can't hit it make sure to check ipfw:

```
# ipfw -a l
65535 0 0 allow ip from any to any
```

If you have other rules in there you can:

```
# ipfw flush
```

To remove them.

If none of that works try disabling them both and seeing if you are still unable to connect:

```
# sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=0
#  /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate off
Firewall already disabled
```

If you are still having problems then theres probably a config issue with apache.

Comment: hmmmm... I did mention the above strategy in my comment above a couple of hours ago, but I also mentioned that in spite of being able to "--unblock" the app, it still remains blocked. I am not using `ipfw` (yet), and am sure I have not inadvertently turned it on. This is a brand new Lion machine.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had written the answer out then forgot to hit post. I added some ipfw and disable stuff, let me know if disabling it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have never tinkered with `ipfw` on this machine, and `ipfw -a l` does return `65535 0 0 allow ip from any to any`. I only set up the firewall via Sys Prefs, and inadvertently set `/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd` to block incoming connections. Now I am not in front of my machine, but logged in remotely. I can use `socketfilterfw --unblockapp /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd` and it lists the app as being unblocked `3 :  /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd ( Allow incoming connections ) ` yet apache2 doesn't respond to requests. However, if I turn `socketfilterfw --setglobalstate off` then it works fine.

Comment: Did you install a new apache?  Are you sure its the one thats running?  On my OS X Lion laptop(pretty much stock) its actually /usr/sbin/httpd that I need to allow for it to work.

Comment: yes, this is apache2 installed via macports under `/opt/local/apache2/`

Comment: Can you enable socketfilterfw and then run /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -d, attempt to connect to apache and add the output or a pastebin of it to the question?